# PowerShell Passing Local Parameters to a Remote Script via Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

Using PowerShell 4.0. I'm trying to run a script remotely that resides on the remote server. I need to pass a variable from my local script to the remote script. I've gone over dozens of posts and tried at least 10 variations but none seem to work. My initial command was:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerList -FilePath $piDeployScript -ArgumentList $SDFEnvironment
```

Where $piDeployScript is the full UNC path to the script on the remote server and $SDFEnvironment is a simple string parameter passed into my script. It looks like the parameter is not getting passed to the script. Is there a simple way to do this? How far off am I?

Update: I don't write the remote scripts, they're written by other groups in the company. The only thing I know is what field(s) need to be passed and they're all positional. I don't know the actual parameter names in the remote scripts. I could get them but I'm trying to write something that will work regardless of the parameters on the remote script. I get passed a list of parameter values (in this case 1 parameter) and send that list of strings to the remote script.

Update: Per @dugas this is the test script I'm running on my own server to test the functionality

```
Param
(
# SDF Environment
[Parameter(Position=0)]
[string]$SDFEnvironment
)
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SDFEnvironment')) 
{
"Script Ran Env $SDFEnvironment"|Out-File -FilePath .\$SDFEnvironment"_LogFile.txt" -Encoding ascii -Force
}
else
{
"Environment Parameter missing"|Out-File -FilePath .\"ERR_LogFile.txt" -Encoding ascii -Force
}
```

Update: Below is the entire section of my local script that runs the Invoke-Command:

```
# Run the specifed script on all computers
Write-Output ("Running command ""{0}"" on server(s) ""{1}"" for   Environment ""{2}"" " -f $piDeployScript,$SDFServerList,$SDFEnvironment)
try
{
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $SDFServerList -Quiet)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SDFServerList -FilePath $piDeployScript -ArgumentList $SDFEnvironment
}
else
{
    Write-Error "Remoting not enabled on one or more of ""$SDFServerList"" "
    exit 1
}
}
catch
{
Write-Error ("Error running script {0} on server(s) {1}. Check log for more detail." -f $piServerScript,$SDFServerList)
exit 1
}
```

and here's the output from that code:

```
Running command "D:\AHP\pi_exceed_presentation\pi_exceed_presentation_deploy.ps1" on server(s) "ad1hfdahp802" for Environment "INT" 
D:\a5\RWS_pi_exceed_presentation\Content_Deploy\trunk\deploy\Deploy-Content.ps1
 : Error running script pi_exceed_presentation_deploy.ps1 on server(s)ad1hfdahp802. Check log for more detail.
```

My bad on the $piDeployScript variable. It's not the UNC to the script, it's the local file system address on the remote server. Is that the problem? Is it looking for the script on my local D: drive? Did I just answer my question?

Just to test my questions above I ran this code in PowerShell from my desktop:

```
$s="ad1hfdahp802"
$SDFEnvironment="INT"
$fp="\\ad1hfdahp802\D$\AHP\pi_exceed_presentation\pi_exceed_presentation_deploy.ps1"
try
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -FilePath $fp -ArgumentList $SDFEnvironment
}
catch
{
    write-output "error running $fp on $s for $SDFEnvironment"
}
```

The code returned with no error, but the remote script didn't run. I logged into the remote server via RDC and ran the remote script locally in PowerShell with and without a parameter and it worked as expected. Now I'm really stumped.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked. Look at the $piDeployScript and confirm there is a parameter defined: param($someParameter). If you can, post the param declaration from the script.

Comment: @dugas - I updated my question with the entire test script I'm running on my test server. The script just verifies the parameter was passed and writes stuff to a log file that is retrieved after the Invoke-Command completes.

Comment: @dugas - Please see the last update. It turns out looking at the output that I'm passing a local filesystem path ("D:\....") instead of a UNC like I thought I was. Does that mean it's looking in my local file system rather than the remote server? If so I can rewrite my script to use a UNC, but that will take some work since I may have a list of servers and the UNC would be different for each one. I'd have to iterate over my list instead of just passing the list to Invoke-Command in $SDFServerList.

Comment: From docs: -FilePath string
       Run the specified local script on one or more remote computers.
       Enter the path and file name of the script, or pipe a script path to Invoke-Command.
       The script must reside on the local computer or in a directory that the local computer can
       access. Use -ArgumentList to specify the values of parameters in the script.
        
       When you use this parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script
       file to a script block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it
       on the remote computer.

Comment: I read that, but I thought I saw a couple of posts where people were using -FilePath with a UNC to a location on the remote server. Assuming PS doesn't care that it's a UNC it shouldn't matter. BUT, I guess it does.  So, how DO I run a script that resides remotely? I have no real choice in this design. I'm trying to automate something that's already in place and run manually. Do I retrieve the script from the server into a variable and put that in a ScriptBlock? If so how do I still use ArgumentList for the params? The docs are confusing given the 16 examples...

Comment: If the script resides remotely then just call the script from within an Invoke-Command's scriptblock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102027/discussion-between-dugas-and-richard-schaefer).

Answer (score 0):

Local script:

```
$server='ad1hfdahp802'
$remotepath='\\ad1hfdahp802\d$\AHP\pi_exceed_presentation\pi_exceed_presentation_deploy.ps1'
$scriptPath='d:\AHP\pi_exceed_presentation\'
$SDFEnvironment='INT'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -FilePath $remotepath -ArgumentList($SDFEnvironment,$scriptPath)
```

Remote Script:

```
Param
(
# SDF Environment
[Parameter(Position=0)]
[string]$SDFEnvironment,

[Parameter(Position=1)]
[string]$scriptPath
)
Write-Output "Running Script - $SDFEnvironment"
Write-Output "Path: $scriptPath"
$outpath=("{0}\{1}_LogFile.txt" -f $scriptPath,$SDFEnvironment)
"Script Ran Env $SDFEnvironment"|Out-File -FilePath $outpath -Encoding ascii -Force
Write-Output "Script Complete"
```

This combination works. Originally the remote script used $PSCommandPath (also tried $PSScriptRoot) to determine the output path but that doesn't work on scripts run remotely. The actual path has to be passed in if you want deterministic placement of output files.